# Heap corruption while using OpenCV datastructure

Tags: c, gcc, opencv, mingw

I am using OpenCV 2.1 with codeblocks (gcc under mingw). Within my code I am trying (for some sane reason) to access the imagedata within IplImage datastructure directly. Kindly refer the code snippet for more details:

```
int main(void)
{
    IplImage* test_image = cvLoadImage("test_image.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    int mysize = test_image->height * test_image->widthStep;
    char* imagedata_ptr = NULL;

    int i   =   0;    
    imagedata_ptr = test_image->imageData;

    char* temp_buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(mysize));
    memcpy(temp_buff,imagedata_ptr,mysize);

    free(temp_buff);
}
```

When I run this code it crashes. On running it in the debug mode it generates a SIGTRAP is due to heap corruption. At first I suspected that this might be a compiler related issue and hence tried running the same code in Visual Studio. But it still crashes. Thats the reason I feel it could be an OpenCV related issue.

NOTE: There are no other instances of program open, this is the only code that I am running, no threading etc is being done here.

Awaiting your comments on the same.

Regards,

Saurabh Gandhi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not allocating enough memory, this:

```
char* temp_buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(mysize))
```

only allocates `sizeof(int)` bytes (probably 4) and that's probably a lot less than you need. Then the [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html) right after that will copy `test_image->height * test_image->widthStep` bytes of data into somewhere that only has space for `sizeof(int)` bytes and you have now scribbled all over your memory and corrupted your heap.

I'd guess that you really want to say this:

```
char *temp_buff = malloc(mysize);
```

And don't cast the return value from [`malloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html), you don't need it and it can hide problems.

Comment: Gosh...I now realize the stupidity of my question and what i was missing...you still made my sunday...Thanks a lot!!

Comment: umm `And don't cast the return value from malloc` unless you are forced to, by compiler :)

Bill Gates says:
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
1>        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: @user757808: "'void' to 'char *'" or "'void *' to 'char *'"? The first one means that you're missing a header, the second means that your compiler is broken (or in C++ mode) as you don't need an explicit cast from `void*` to any other non-function pointer type in C.

Comment: @mu is too short as usual, StackOverflow mangled with my response.